# argparse input can be file, directory or stdin

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that take input from a **file or stdin**. It looks like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I know that the following will take **file or directory** as input:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='+', help='Path of a file or a folder of files.')
args = parser.parse_args()

full_paths = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path) for path in args.infile]
for path in full_paths:
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print("File : " + path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        print("Directory : " + path)
```

How can I get any one of the three (**stdin** or, **file** or, **directory**) as input using argparse.

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve. When you are reading a file/stdin what are you expecting? How does taking a folder differ from these? I don't think there is an `argparse` builtin that will do this in one line, you will have to determine whether you're looking at a file or folder, and process each correctly otherwise default to stdin.

Comment: You don't have to use `FileType`.  Just accept a string (or strings), and use your own code to open then file or set the dir.